# dplyr select many columns performance

Tags: r, performance, select, dplyr

**Goal:**
I try to select complete (without `NA`) columns of a `data.frame`/`matrix` which have a lot of columns (>100k).

**Method:** I compared the performance obtained in *dplyr* (with a data.frame) and in *base* (with a matrix or a data.frame) but it seems that the first method (1 line dplyr) lasts forever and rises an error when stopped.

**Example:** with 50k columns

```
library(dplyr)

# Dummy data
nbcol <- 50000
nbrow <- 5
M <- matrix(runif(nbcol*nbrow), nbrow)
M[M < .01] <- NA # 1% NA
M2 <- as.data.frame(M)


# Dplyr 1 line: 107seconds
system.time({
  select(M2, which(apply(M2, 2, function(x) !any(is.na(x)))))
})

# Dplyr 2 lines: 51 seconds
system.time({
  colind <- which(apply(M2, 2, function(x) !any(is.na(x))))
  select(M2, colind)
})

# Base data.frame: 0.53 seconds
system.time({
  M2[,which(apply(M2, 2, function(x) !any(is.na(x))))]
})

# Base matrix: 0.12 seconds
system.time({
  M[,which(apply(M, 2, function(x) !any(is.na(x))))]
})
```

Is this an expected result or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: I wouldn't consider this a case where I'd choose to use **dplyr** at all. If you really need to do this in a pipe/chain setting, just use the **magrittr** aliases like `extract`. But more generally, you don't want to use `apply` on a data.frame, it will be slow. You want one of `lapply`, `sapply` or `vapply`.

Comment: `M2[, which(sapply(M2, function(x) !any(is.na(x))))]` is the fastest way. I find `dplyr` select to be very useful, but not for this type of conditional selections.

Comment: "of a data.frame/matrix" -- if you care about performance, you should not be indifferent between these two. And adding to joran's list, you might consider using `colSums` with `is.na`... `system.time(M[, colSums(is.na(M)) == 0L])` is zero on my computer.

Comment: Thanks for this nice alternatives. My point is not only to find the fastest way (since the base way is fast enough) but more to be ensured that dplyr is not a good choice here, and ideally to understand why it is that slow (in particular the 1 line method).

Comment: I think dplyr is not a good fit, but primarily because dplyr is designed to work with data.frames and your (example) data fits naturally in a matrix.

Comment: Have you tried `select_if(~(!any(is.na(.))))` instead of using which + apply family? Just curious.